# Recording IP Camera in QT

Tags: qt, qt-creator, ip-camera, qmediaplayer

I am busy with writing a program that is able to view an IP camera and also have a playback option available.
To realize this i have been looking to record the feed that i now have running in my program using the Qmediaplayer.
From what i understand it is not possible to use Qmediarecorder to record this feed. All the examples that use Qmediarecorder use the Qcamera class.
Is there a way to record a stream from an IP camera (mjpeg, h.264 ) with the Qmediarecorder or any other QT tool ?

If not ? what is a good library to use for this kind of application?

Answer (score 0):

**libvlc** may be the library you can looking for, there is also a c++ - qt wrapper that simplifies the usage of library in c++ and qt : **vlc-qt library** :https://vlc-qt.tano.si/ . record and playback availability of library of vlc player is present in this wrapper